# Typeorm, Define a new entity and populate it with default values and foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

Let's say we have a user entity already defined and it has 3 rows. We create another entity called Usage after sometime and add one-to-one relation with User. Is it possible to prefill the usage table having 3 rows related to user table with default values ?

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  username: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @OneToOne(() => Usage)
  usage: Usage;}



@Entity()  
export class Usage {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({default:0})
  views: number;



  @OneToOne(() => User)
  @JoinColumn()
  User: User; }
```